# Multi Function Javascript Stop Other if Alert Cancel

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function executed onclick:

```
function delete_image() {
        //alert;
        var result = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');
        if(result) { ....delete the image.... }
        }

function new_image() { ....Do SOmething.... }
```

Then I call that by

```
<a onclick="setNewUploadOnDelete()">Delete</a>
```

I need if the "alert" of delete_image function is "cancel" then just stop the second function. I try below code but not work.

```
function setNewUploadOnDelete() {
var retvalue;
retvalue = delete_image();
if(retvalue == false) { return retvalue; }
return = new_image();
}
```

Is there any advice please?

Comment: You can not pause the execution of code. You can only "jump" to another code. That's the way computers work. Your delete_image() should just create a question panel, while deleting will be done in another function, when user presses Confirm button.

Answer (score 1):

`setNewUploadOnDelete` can be refactored to:

```
function setNewUploadOnDelete() {
  return delete_image ? new_image() : false;
}
```

Here we're using [Conditional Statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).  This is simple enough that you may not need a function to do it.

On another note, it's generally not a good idea to use `onclick` to trigger JavaScript for reasons of performance and separation of concerns.  Have a read into [adding event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: ha i like yours way better.

Comment: It's simple and nice. However I need the retvalue to done this.

Comment: The function is returning either `new_image()` if `delete_image` is true, and `false` otherwise.